# Canvas children transparency

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

Given a canvas with black background and some white children on it:

[image]

How can I make all children transparent also through canvas background? Behind the canvas may be an image or other content. All solutions that I found are not satisfying:

- Render the canvas to PNG image and turn all white color to transparency. In this case I would loose all benefits of a vector graphic when using the canvas in a viewbox.
- Create one invers child of all children and render it in black on a transparent canvas. But I'm not shure if that's possible.

Note: The children of the canvas may be changed so I'm not searching for a static solution (e.g. a fixed path around all children).

Any ideas how to create such a mask?

Comment: It would help if you posted the xaml of what you already have

Answer (score 1):

Create a geometry with holes and use it with a Path element, e.g. like this:

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <Path Fill="Black"
          Data="M0,0 L1000,0 1000,1000 0,1000Z M100,100 L200,100 200,200 100,200Z"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: How can I create such a hole-path dynamically based on the canvas children? There may be more than one child and the user can edit the canvas children. So a fixed path doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Nobody can solve your exact problem, because you didn't tell us much about it. Anyway, there is plenty of online documentation available. Start reading about PathGeometry.